# how to run multiple IP addresses to be allocated off a single Ethernet port. VoIP

Tags: switch, voip, ip-address, aruba

Implementing hosted VoIP with connection of desk handset to Apple Macs. Gbit to desktop Cat5, Aruba 2920 PoE J9836 Layer 3 Switch. Line will be separate 10Mb, separate router too.

**Question:** How can the Aruba manage the IP traffic of the Mac and the separate IP of the phone? On one port and one cable?

Answers or links to articles greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Simon.

Comment: Is the phone plugged into the MAC or vice versa?  Are the addresses on the same subnet?

Comment: Hi. Wall to Mac (10.0.3.x) to handset (unknown as yet). I'm thinking a different subnet.

Comment: How does the handset connect to the Mac?  Most Macs nowadays only have a single Ethernet port.  The normal way to do this would switch to handset to Mac

Comment: Ah, yes. Switch to handset to Mac is the method. Thanks Qualeboy.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to use a tagged VLAN for the phone traffic and a different untagged VLAN for the Mac/PC traffic.  The phone is either manually configured with the VLAN tag for its traffic, or it can learn it through LLDP-MED.  The phone passes the untagged traffic through to the Mac/PC untouched.

If 10.1.10.0/24 is the Mac/PC network and 10.1.20.0/24 is the voice network then the config sets up interface 1 for a phone and Mac:

Vlan 10 
name Macs 
 
ip address 10.1.10.1 255.255.255.0

Vlan 20 
voice 
name Voice 
ip address 10.1.20.1 255.255.255.0

interface 1 
untagged vlan 10 
tagged vlan 20

The "voice" option under VLAN 20 allows the switch to signal the voice VLAN to the phone using LLDP-MED

Answer (score 0):

If the MAC sits between the phone and the rest of the network, then your MAC has to act like a switch and forward traffic to the phone.  I've never seen software to do that (but then again, I've never really looked either).  You want to be able to prioritize traffic based on QoS markings, so your voice quality doesn't suffer if you do something CPU or network intensive while talking on the phone.

If you are going to use separate subnets, then you also need to MAC to understand 802.1q VLAN tagging, and forward VLAN traffic to the right device.